# Android GridView to fit Screen Height

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a fixed size 2x3 grid, a total of 6 items. Is there any way i can fit the gridview items to fill the screen ? 
and, is gridview a good choice in this case ? or should i use something else ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know that you have 6 items, why not just create 6 blocks. i.e. If you have 6 images, why not just create 6 image views?

[image]

Ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation = "horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:src="@drawable/sunny"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:src="@drawable/sunny"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation = "horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:src="@drawable/sunny"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:src="@drawable/sunny"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation = "horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:src="@drawable/sunny"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:src="@drawable/sunny"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's usually bad idea to use nested hierarchies as it leads to performance issues. More info here: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html

Answer (score 2):

If your `GridView` will always be of fixed size and you need to fit all items on the screen simultaneously (so you don't need scrolling capabilities) I suggest you use [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) instead. It'll be easy to fit the whole GridLayout inside the screen, by setting its `layout_width` and `layout_height` properties to the `match_parent`.